# Target class [App\Utilities\getIp] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm new to Laravel.

I've created a `file.php` in **App/Utilities** folder.

It contains a class that gets user IP address.

Class name is `getIp`.

And in a partial view, I use this code :

```
@inject('ip', 'App\Utilities\getIp')
```

Laravel is giving me this error :

> Target class [App\Utilities\getIp] does not exist. (View: /var/www/html/adopte/resources/views/layouts/partials/_header.blade.php)

Can you help, please?

Comment: how are you using the class after the service injection??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name just needs to be the same as the class name. That simply should do.